# Explanation of Surah 9:64?

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer, arabic

It says something like "say mock [as you wish]." in part of it in Sahih International translation

We should not assist in sinning

We should command good and forbid evil

So how do we tell munafiqs "mock [us/Islam/Muslims]? mocking is a sin and not a good act.

How is it explained?

And do not say it is abrogated JUST BECAUSE it seems to contradict other verses. This is not a convincing method if used without evidence (hadith evidence).

Comment: What requires explanation here? It is a threat. The intended meaning is to convey that 'if you mock you will face consequences' which essentially means 'do not mock'. Examples of such are found in several verses apart from this such as [39:8](https://quran.com/39/8?translations=20),  [18:29](https://quran.com/18/29?translations=20),  [9:105](https://quran.com/9/105?translations=20) , [41:40](https://quran.com/41/40?translations=20) etc.

Answer (score 2):

**The Ayah:**

> They hypocrites are apprehensive lest a surah be revealed about them, informing them of what is in their hearts. Say, "Mock [as you wish]; indeed, Allah will expose that which you fear." (Al-Quran-9:64)

There are two types of hypocrites. One kind of hypocrites among them used to say that they were muslim to the Muslims and actually they were not Muslims. They used to make fun of Islam and at the same time, they were afraid of being mentioned for lying to Muslims.

In the ayah/ayat, "mock [as you wish]" means they won't get any benefits from mocking. Your days of mocking is going to expire soon. Allah will reveal what is in their hearts. So they should not mock.